# In azure how to share mysql database resource with group member

Tags: mysql, azure, azureportal

We are new to azure but want to learn it and use it to host a MySQL database for our school project.

I have created a MySQL database within azure and added my friend as a member to both the resource group "RUC" and the MySQL database resource itself.

But he can't access it within his own azure portal. How is that.

We are both on the dreamspark subscription which is free for students :)

Comment: Does your friend see your Azure Subscription when he logs in the portal?

Comment: Am I creating I the wrong way?

Comment: Can you please update your question and describe in detail how you're setting things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your friend has logged into portal.azure.com, if you click on the top right section where your username is, a dropdown mean will appear where your azure subscription will be at. He then has to click on it to be able to see the resource group.

If you dont see it then please check the user permission on the resourcegroup and make sure you have added him correctly.

Comment: That was it. Thank you :)